# Method in C# to return the font of a string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, fonts

Is there a method in C# that accepts a string parameter and returns the font of the string?
I know of :

```
if (currentControl.Font.Bold == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bold");
}
```

to find the font of a control. I woud like a method that does that for a string. Something like:

```
private static Font GetFont(string myString)
{
    Font stringFont = myString.Font;
    return stringFont;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `string` is a text, only text, no style. if you want styled text you can create class like that

Comment: A string doesn't have a font...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, as strings don't have fonts. Only controls have fonts.

More specifically, a font is not an inherent property of a string. The string is just the collection of characters that composes the string itself. The font property is only imbued when you go to *display* that string somewhere, e.g., in a control on your form. Then, the font property of the control applies. So, the font follows the *display element*, not the content.